# Expected Hitting time one of two barriers Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I was wondering if there has been some results for the following question:

Let $X(t)=\mu dt+\sigma dB_t$ ($t\ge0$, $X(0)=X_0$, $\sigma>0$, $\mu\ne 0$) be a diffusion process with constant drift and diffusion. Suppose $X_0\in (b,B)\subseteq \Re$. Define $\tau\equiv \inf\{t\,|\,X(t)\in \{b,B\}\}$ be the first-hitting time (an almost surely finite stopping time). Then what is the probability (density) that the diffusion process stops at time $t\ge 0$ at $b$ (namely, the density for the event $\{X(\tau)=b, \tau=t\}$)?

I hope someone can give me a hint or some references. Many thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "density for the event"? Obviously, we have $\mathbb{P}(X_{\tau}=b, \tau=t) \leq \mathbb{P}(X_t = b) = 0$ for each fixed $t>0$.

Comment: Note that it is not an almost surely finite stopping time if $\mu<0$

Comment: @saz Probably this is not very rigorous, but I am conceiving the following problem: Given that $X(\tau)=b$, what is the conditional distribution of $\tau$, say, $F(t\,|\,X(\tau)=b)\equiv \mathbb P(\tau\le t\,|\, X(\tau)=b )$. So by density I meant the density corresponding to $F$. (I am not sure if this problem is well-defined, but It is based on my intuition.) Corrections welcome.